# How to replace "texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));" with another one

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

I am new in libgdx. I am trying to randomly replace the Texture after I hit a button. Here is my code:

---

```
public static Texture texture;

Random rand = new Random();
int x = rand.nextInt(2);

if (x == 0)
{texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));}

else if(x == 1)
{texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture2.png"));}

ready = new TextureRegion(texture, 354, 498, 204, 42);

ready.flip(false, true);
```

---

please help me with this, I'm really stuck here right now. Thank You..

Is there a way that I can replace my current texture with a randomly pick texture in a click of a button? I tried .dispose() before randomly pick a new texture, but it wont reload the new texture. this is basically my problem. Thank You..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new TextureRegion each time, you could try using `ready.setTexture(texture)`. This has fixed similar problems for me with Drawables.

Comment: thank you for your answer.. I tried it, but still it didn't work.

Comment: Is there a way that I can replace my current texture with a randomly pick texture in a click of a button? I tried .dispose() before randomly pick a new texture, but it wont reload the new texture. this is basically my problem. Thank You..